# Identify calling process of a php file

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a php file that is being executed at frequent intervals on my server. I've checked crontab and the cronjobs, I cannot find the source. Is there something I can print from the php file to identify the calling process?

Comment: how do you know its being executed? that source may help uncover some additional information

Comment: The script writes to a mysql db on another server. The db update keeps happening, I just cant figure out who's doing the calling

Comment: Possibly, delete the file then check the system error logs. The problem is that PHP is running the script, but something is calling PHP to run it, not sure if you can actually figure out which thing is calling the PHP executable.

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks like puppetd was running the script.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question, but
If you need to kill the process you can use : killall crond
try "ps -aux" to get the process list

Answer (score 1):

perhaps its being called by another crontab as a `curl` or a `wget` request. are there any other machines that are being used?

also check the timestamps to determine if they are regularly occurring vs just happening often. if they are not occurring at a (roughly) equal amount of time per execution, then its probably not cron at all. if its not cron, then its occurring as a result of some event. and then you'll just be looking for that script's url in your PHP code to see which page calls it.

Comment: how it works is that I have a db server and lots of other servers. This php file is present in the home directory of each of the servers and they advertize themselves by writing an entry to the db everyday